# Can't boot into Windows 8.1 after Installing Ubuntu on pendrive

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8, usb-drive

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a pendrive, by following this tutorial: http://www.fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/installubuntutousbdrive.html .

The problem is that when I turn on the laptop without the pendrive I get "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.[...]" grub message. 
But when I turn it on with the pendrive, I am able to boot into Ubuntu or Windows 8.1 and both works fine.

Can anyone explain why this happened?
What can I do to boot directly into Windows when the pendrive is not inserted?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just go to the UEFI settings (UEFI replace the old BIOS) and change the boot order for the Windows entry. The guide you linked is somehow outadate in the sense it isn't applicable for UEFI systems. Any factory installed Windows 8 or newer is in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem. Just to mention for anyone with the same issue: when the pendrive is inserted, you have to go to Boot menu and choose which system do you want, otherwise it will boot directly into the first one (in my case - Windows).